# Reactive Store variables in Svelte: undefined?

Tags: javascript, svelte, store, reactive

very simple attempt to get reactive vars from the store.
In my *App.svelte*:

```
import { config } from "./store/config.js";
$: config = $config || {};
```

In my *./store/config.js*:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export let config = writable({
  languageCode: "NL"
});
```

a simple `console.log(config);` in *App.svelte* though results in "undefined".

rule 6 of [this official Svelte example](https://svelte.dev/repl/7aabd35ed55a4c51bcdc76a4c39be18f?version=3.52.0) shows the same syntax doesn't it?

Comment: Try this: $: console.log($config). 
You need the $config syntax to auto subscribe to the store.
And de $: syntax to console.log() every store change.

Answer (score 1):

The log results in `undefined` because

> **Reactive statements run after other script code and before the component markup is rendered**, whenever the values that they depend on have changed.
> [Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive)

It can be reactive as well

```js
$: console.log(config);
```

(I don't think though that it's possible to import something and create a reactive variable with the same name here `config`? And I'm not sure about this pattern. In the linked (official?) example it could be avoided by initializing `$selected` with `0`)